# Embarrassingly parallel and Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing, tensorflow2.0

Edit:
Based on the comments, I am trying to make some clarification here. I haven't asked question online before, so let me try again and see if this time is better.

I am running a simulation study with Tensorflow. In the experiment, I will generate 1000 samples X1, X2,...,X1000. Each X1 has n observations. On each Xi, I will fit a neural network and save some outputs Yi.

So my algorithm looks like the following:

```
for i in range(1000):
    generate Xi
    fit nerual network.
    produce and save Yi
```

As you can see, the algorithm is very inefficient because each iteration is independent of the other. Is there a elegant way to parallel the simulation which works for training with GPU?

Thanks.

Comment: You should format the question in a better way. It is very hard to understand the exact problem that you are facing. Also, it would help if you shared what you tried to research before and what roadblocks you have hit

Comment: Is that title a joke? Nice ;) As @SimasJoneliunas said though, it’s difficult to make recommendations when we know nothing about the task and your program.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I have updated my question. Please let me know if there is something still unclear.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I have updated my question. Please let me know if there is something still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

If you write the entire algorithm as you described it inside a graph (e.g. place it inside a [tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/function)), then TF may be able to run the iterations in parallel. See `parallel_iterations` in [tf.while_loop](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop). Note that this is on best-effort basis, and only works if data dependencies and the presence of operations with side effects allow it. You'll also need to think about concurrency if different steps fit the same neural network.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look that these functions and give them a try.

Comment: I tried tf while loop but somehow I don't see the parallel_iterations argument makes any difference.Even with a simple example, I don't see any difference.

Comment: iteration = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 1010)
def print_fun(iteration):
    2 + 2
    iteration+=1
    return (iteration,)
r = tf.while_loop(c, print_fun, [iteration], parallel_iterations=10)